# The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match TFLite Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to ML, but thanks to the documentation and the community, I'm developing in this direction. Now I have stumbled upon an error and for several days I could not solve it, what is the problem and how to solve it?

I looked at the tutorials, I didn't seem to forget anything. On the XMl layout there is a picture, a text where the data comes from, their ids match

I want to open an object, take a picture of it and say what it is based on my trained model

Problem: the application crashes on line 194:
`inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)`

````
class SortingFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
 
    //ML
    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    lateinit var appCtx: Application
    lateinit var btnMLrn : Button
 
 
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public fun checkandGetpermissions() {
        if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(
                requireActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 100)
        } else {
            requireActivity().showToast("Camera permission granted")
        }
    }
 
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requireActivity().showToast("Camera permission granted")
            } else {
 
                requireActivity().showToast("Permission Denied")
            }
        }
    }
 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.v(LOG_SORTING_FRAGMENT, "onCreate called")
 
        // handling permissions
        checkandGetpermissions()
 
        appCtx = requireActivity().application
 
    }
 
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.v(LOG_SORTING_FRAGMENT, "onCreateView called")
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sorting, container, false)
 
        btnMLrn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMLrn) 
 
        fltNtf = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fltNtf)
        fltNtf.setOnClickListener(this)
 
        btnMLrn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
 
            var camera : Intent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            startActivityForResult(camera, 200)
        })
        return rootView
    } 
 
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
 
        if(requestCode == 250){
 
            img_view.setImageURI(data?.data)
 
            var uri : Uri?= data?.data
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireActivity().contentResolver, uri)
        }
        else if(requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
 
            var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true)
            val model = ModelUnquant.newInstance(requireActivity())
 
            var tbuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
            var byteBuffer = tbuffer.buffer
 
// Creates inputs for reference.
            val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
 
// Runs model inference and gets result.
            val outputs = model?.process(inputFeature0)
            val outputFeature0 = outputs?.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
 
            var max = outputFeature0?.let { it1 -> getMax(it1.floatArray) }
 
            val labels = appCtx.assets.open("labels.txt").bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }.split("\n")
 
            sorttext.setText(labels[max!!])
 
// Releases model resources if no longer used.
            if (model != null) {
                model.close()
            }
        }}
 
 
    fun getMax(arr: FloatArray): Int {
        var ind = 0;
        var min = 0.0f;
 
        for (i in 0..10) {
            if (arr[i] > min) {
                min = arr[i]
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        return ind
    }
} ```
````

Comment: If your model's input is [1,224,224,3] then use directly model.process(byteBuffer) , comment out the line that gives you the error and see if this solves your issue

Comment: Thanks for the help, but then Android Studio complains about the parameter: Type mismatch.
Required:
TensorBuffer
Found:
ByteBuffer!

Comment: Can you post the original error from the logcat?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Hello, sorry for taking so long. It just worked for a while, I thought. As it turned out, it just showed one value( here is a complete error: https://pastebin.com/MU3nV3YQ . Running the model from Google, everything works, I made my own using: https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image

Comment: Yes, when there is no error. It just constantly selects the same element. The model is trained well. There are 500+ different photos of different objects everywhere